# Error ORA-00904 in SQL developer. Seemly no fix online that works that I can find while creating a table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have seen many posts regarding the seemingly infamous ORA-00904 yet nothing seems to be helping. I am creating 2 tables (for now, more to come later) which are as follows;

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    EmployeeID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID),
    customerID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT employee_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID),
    LastName CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    MiddleInitial CHAR(1), 
    FirstName CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    Region CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DateOfHire VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Skill VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ProjectID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(ProjectID) REFERENCES Project(ProjectID), /*This is yet another table with a foreign key which needs to be sorted*/
    CustomerName Char(255) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber INT NOT NULL,
    Region CHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

but every time I run it, I get error;

```
Error starting at line : 4 in command -
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    EmployeeID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID),
    customerID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT employee_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY(customerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID),
    LastName CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    MiddleInitial CHAR(1), 
    FirstName CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    Region CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DateOfHire VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Skill VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
Error report -
ORA-00904: "CUSTOMERID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED!

Comment: `"customerID"` <> `customerID`.

Comment: @jarlh, can you explain? I cant see where ive gone wrong!

Comment: Be consistent, either quoting or no quoting.

Comment: @jarlh, from what I can see, there is NO comments within my code at all, it simply seems to be within my error output when the quotes are appearing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle by default converts all names to UpperCase if you don't enquote them. (Edit: At the time of this answer the Foreign Key Constraint in the starting post did contain a quoted column name).

So, your constraint tries to find a column named "customerID" whereas the real name of your column is "CUSTOMERID".

Either enquote your column:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    EmployeeID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID),
    "customerID" INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT employee_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY ("customerID") REFERENCES customer(CustomerID),
    LastName CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    MiddleInitial CHAR(1), 
    FirstName CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    Region CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DateOfHire VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Skill VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Don't use quotes on your FOREIGN KEY constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    EmployeeID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID),
    customerID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT employee_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES customer(CustomerID),
    LastName CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    MiddleInitial CHAR(1), 
    FirstName CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    Region CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DateOfHire VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Skill VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Or use quotes and write it uppercase in your foreign key constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    EmployeeID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID),
    customerID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT employee_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY ("CUSTOMERID") REFERENCES customer(CustomerID),
    LastName CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    MiddleInitial CHAR(1), 
    FirstName CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    Region CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DateOfHire VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Skill VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

As already mentioned, keeping the style consistent is recommended to prevent future problems, so Option 2 would be the easiest solution. Otherwise you need to enquote all columns to be consistent.

/Edit:
I just tried it - this definitely works with Oracle 12C:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
CustomerID INT,
PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
)
```

Followed by:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    EmployeeID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID),
    customerID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT employee_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY(customerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID),
    LastName CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    MiddleInitial CHAR(1), 
    FirstName CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    Region CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DateOfHire VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Skill VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: there is no quotes at all in my code as you can see from above... any other ideas? ill try enquoting it now and see if it helps

Comment: thats a negative... tried all of the above options ```CREATE TABLE Employee(
    EmployeeID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID),
    customerID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT employee_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES customer(customerID),
    LastName CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    MiddleInitial CHAR(1), 
    FirstName CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    Region CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DateOfHire VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Skill VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);```

Comment: I just tried the query you changed to in your edit. It works. You need to check all your columns. I'll edit working code into my answer.

Comment: I added a completely working example. I tried with an Oracle 12C database, it does not throw any errors. Also make sure to check the casing of your column in the Customer-Table.

Comment: I have still got the error, that fixed its self when I deleted the other foreign key out of the customer table. is there an issue with having multiple foreign keys within many tables?

Comment: No, there is no such issue. But if the not working foreign key constraint prevented the table from being created correctly this might have been the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The *referenced* table needs to created *before* the foreign key reference.  One method is to create the tables first and then add the foreign key references:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    EmployeeID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID),
    customerID INT NOT NULL,
    LastName CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    MiddleInitial CHAR(1), 
    FirstName CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    Region CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DateOfHire VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Skill VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ProjectID INT NOT NULL,
    -- FOREIGN KEY(ProjectID) REFERENCES Project(ProjectID), /*This is yet another table with a foreign key which needs to be sorted*/
    CustomerName Char(255) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber INT NOT NULL,
    Region CHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

alter table Employee add CONSTRAINT employee_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES Customer (CustomerID)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=946bb7fc1fc5822cec355e3e31f24a81) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that I commented out the foreign key constraint to `Project`.

Also, in most data models you can just order the table creates -- there are no cycles in the foreign key "linkages".  However, because you have not defined `Project`, I am suggesting this more general approach.